# What phrase can be used to ask if a French girl is single?

Tags: société

As in the title, how to say in French to a mid-20 year old French girl, literally and culturally, "are you girl still single so I can ask you out ?".

"Es-tu disponible?", "Tu es célibataire?" seem awkward, for me.

Will there be any difference if we have known each other several weeks and if we have just met ?

Comment: T'as quelqu'un dans ta vie ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, any awkwardness you might feel towards "célibataire" comes from "celibate" being related to religious beliefs in English? As far as I know, there is no stigma or negative connotation attached to "célibataire".

I have used "Êtes-vous célibataire ?" a couple of times myself in the not-really-trying-to-ask-them-out-but-rather-out-of-curiosity context, and without any problem.

Comment: *Célibataire* implies being "not married", i.e. With the fast decline of the marital union you can be *célibataire* and yet involved in a relationship.

Comment: @Laure In my experience, célibataire means not involved in a relationship (either married, juste couple, etc.). Another translation possible is "Es-tu en couple" ?

Comment: @Larme In France *célibataire* is still felt as having taken no official union, you can *être en couple* (which is indeed a very good phrase for what OP wants) - and still be *célibataire*....

Comment: @Larme You're right, if you are _célibataire_, it means that you are not engaged in a relationship. So you **cannot** be at the same time _en couple_ and _célibataire_.